# CSP works with Next.js prod build but not on dev server

Tags: javascript, next.js, content-security-policy

I've been trying to implement CSP on my Next.js application, and I've managed to get it working when running `next build` and `next start`, but for some reason when running `next dev` it doesn't render at all, and  the following error is logged on the console:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
    at ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-refresh-utils/dist/runtime.js (react-refresh.js?ts=1710261451116:30:26)
```

I tried following the suggestions in the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy) as well as in [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49648) of generating a nonce using middleware, but I was only able to get CSP working by adding the header to `next.config.js`. I'm also using the pages router, if that info is helpful. This is what the relevant parts of my `next.config.js` file looks like:

```js
const cspHeader = `
  default-src 'self';
  script-src 'self';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com;
  font-src 'self' https:;
  img-src 'self' blob: data:;
  object-src 'none';
  connect-src 'self' https:;
  upgrade-insecure-requests;
`

module.exports = {
  ...
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
            value: cspHeader.replace(/\n/g, ''),
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue (preferably without modifying the CSP header just for local development)?